# StreamSource: InputStream vs FileInputStream

Tags: java, xml, xsd, inputstream

When using

```
ZipArchiveEntry schemaEntry = zipFile.getEntry("metadata.xml");
InputStream schemaIS = zipFile.getInputStream(schemaEntry);
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(schemaIS));
```

I get

```
s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than     'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'archive'.
```

But when using

```
File schemaFile = new File("/somedir/schema.xsd");
InputStream schemaFileIS = new FileInputStream(schemaFile);
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(schemaFileIS));
```

It works properly, i.e: it shows schema errors.

The same goes to the .xml file I want to validate. If I create a StreamSource from File it all works. But if I use an InputStream (from a zip) it just skips validation (doesn't throw an exception and it should).

So, If I use StreamSource(FileInputStream) both .xsd and .xml are correctly loaded. But if I use InputStream (and I must use this) it just doesn't work.

EDIT: 
Changed

```
ZipArchiveEntry schemaEntry = zipFile.getEntry("metadata.xml");
```

to

```
ZipArchiveEntry schemaEntry = zipFile.getEntry("metadata.xsd");
```

And it's working. Thanks to the @fge replier.

Comment: We really don't have enough information to go on here. What is `schema.xsd`? What does it contain? What is `schemaEntry`? Is it a zipped version of the file?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis
`schema.xsd` is a xml schema.
`schemaEntry` is `ZipArchiveEntry`

Comment: Someone replied saying that `metadata.xml` was not `metadata.xsd`, and of course that person was right. I just changed `metadata.xml` to `metadata.xsd` and it's working now. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: That was me... Anyway, problem solved but look at my answer if you're using Java 7

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I have to use Java 6.